# Matlab fminsearch error

Tags: matlab

I have a problem in a very simple code like below.

```
syms c p;
y=symfun(c^2+p, [c,p]);
fminsearch(y, [-1,-1]);


Error using symfun/subsref (line 113)
Symbolic function expected 2 inputs and received 1.

Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) is a *numerical* minimization routine, you don't need symbolic functions here. The function should have one input, which can however be a vector or a matrix. Its output must be numeric, not symbolic. A correct example of usage is

```
fminsearch(@(x) x(1)^2+x(2) , [-1,-1])
```

where the input is x, a vector with two components x(1) and x(2).

But you can still use your symbolic function by converting it to numeric as follows:

```
syms c p;
y=symfun(c^2+p, [c,p]);
fminsearch(@(x) subs(y, {c, p}, {x(1), x(2)}), [-1,-1])
```

By the way, there are no minimum points of this function, so the algorithm fails to converge. Try `c^2+p^2` to get meaningful output.

Comment: @I disagree Thanks. I already know a function-handle correct. But I should use  'symfun', because I need to plus the functions, for example _f1+f2_ and so on. Function-handle is not available for plus.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but It still gives me error :                              `Undefined function 'formula' for input arguments of type 'double'.
Error in symfun (line 37)
            y = y@sym(formula(x));
Error in sym/subs (line 121)
        G = symfun(G,argnames(F));
Error in @(x)subs(y,[c,p],[x(1),x(2)])
Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});`

Comment: The three-line code I posted executes exactly as written on my machine (Matlab R2013a). There is no line `y = y@sym(formula(x));` either in my code, or in your question. I answered your question as it was posed; I am not responsible for debugging the other 200 lines of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Mine is 2012b.